# No login screen on startup, works after logging in and logging out again

Tags: login, 15.04, lightdm, systemd

I installed Ubuntu on a client's computer. At first - no issue, but after some updates and installs (including burg, which was not the problem as the problem remained after removing it, I could not get lightdm to load correctly, until I switched to upstart.

Is this a known problem with a known fix?

#### New Details:

- The problem seems to go away once I log into a desktop and log out.
  The issue seems to be, however, that I'm unable to log out from Unity
  (I have to double check this), but I'm able to log out from KDE.
- Switching between TTYs is impossible once logged in, however (not
  tested on KDE yet, I will update with more information as I go).
- A cursor is visible on boot, but the touchpad is disabled, and has to
  be manually enabled after booting up.
- The problem is also occurring when using upstart, though this was not
  the case originally.
- The system in question uses intel graphics (I will update the question with precise specs later). There is no graphics card so it's not using Hybrid graphics.
- It is possible to log in from the blank lightdm screen because apparently despite the login screen not being rendered, it is working just fine (just type the password press <kbd>enter</kbd> and you're in.
- To reiterate, you can switch to TTYs ***until*** you're logged in (at least this is the case with Unity). Once logged in, as I mentioned earlier, this is no longer possible.

### Second Update:

- I purged Lightdm.
- I've switched the system to SDDM for the time being.
- I'm now waiting for Lightdm to re-install (connection is being rather slow these days).
- Once Lightdm is reinstalled I will try changing the wallpaper (one suggestion I received) or trying another greeter.
- I did search the web for info but came up dry on this precise issue though I did find similar issues.

### System Information:

Acer Aspire E1-431-2867:

- 2GB of RAM
- Intel Celeron B820 (1.7Ghz, 2MB L3 cache)
- Intel HD Graphics
- The rest... irrelevant and too long to list ;)

I will leave the question open for a little in case someone can find an answer (if someone does, then I'll still give the bounty I was going to).

At the moment however, I'm out of time and have decided to switch to SDDM so I can return the system to the owner.

Comment: At first the system was working fine. This means it is  a change you made to the system that is causing this. Why not post edited bash history, and list all the changes made to the system?

Comment: have you experienced these problems after installing `systemd` ? I experienced a similar issue when I installed it on another Linux distro. Everything was frozen but other TTYs work when I issued `init 3` from SSH

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal not quite the same. Ubuntu 15.04 comes with `systemd` and uses it by default. Nothing is truly frozen in this case, and it seems the TTY issue is gone (though I'm not sure why - to be honest the whole situation is really confusing as it is not being consistent!).

Comment: Just to check, can you verify that if you run `systemctl status default.target`, then it displays information for `graphical.target`?

Comment: Does the problem appear in the guest logon as well?

Comment: @Fabby I can't get to the guest login after booting (which was when the problem shows up). I am going to return the system tomorrow though, so am thinking I might just switch to SDDM and leave it alone :(

Comment: 500 rep!  gone with the wind!!!   Aargh!

Comment: @saiarcot895 yes, it works.

Comment: Ok, just checking to see what the default target to load up was.

Comment: @RolandiXor Could you try my answer here https://askubuntu.com/q/697529/26246

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the person who had the issue has since had no complaints and it makes no sense at this point worrying over it. Systemd is problematic, but also not worth my time and effort to figure out.